# 'expect' was used when there was no current spec AFTER tests complete successfully

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular6, karma-jasmine

Blown pretty much a full day now trying to get async testing to work.  For various tests I need to call whenStable(), wait for it and then perform a test.  As soon as I try to use any promises, the tests run through, all pass, then it pauses at the end for a few seconds and I get the error: "Uncaught Error: 'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out"

```
  it('should switch tabs', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(C2Component);
    const component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
  }));
```

If this is the only async test I have in, and I comment it out, tests run through (all pass) and I get no error at the end.  As soon as I add this in, they run through (all pass) and then I get the error at the end.

karma.conf.js:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

I've tried these various versions of the test:

```
  it('should switch tabs', (done) => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(C2Component);
    const component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
      done();
    });
  });
```

```
  it('should switch tabs', async () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(C2Component);
    const component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    await fixture.whenStable()
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Related package versions:

```
"karma": "^1.7.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.4",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
```

Also now tried with versions:

```
"jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
"karma": "^4.0.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
"karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
```

Comment: Upgraded jasmine, karma and a few other test related things.  Now if I use any of the async test examples listed above I get:

`An error was thrown in afterAll\nTypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null\n    at <Jasmine>\n    at HtmlReporter.jasmineDone`

Removing the async tests again causes the them to pass and run fine with no errors.

Comment: So - seems like it has something to do with running fixture.detectChanges().  There was another test (non-async) that makes this call.  Once I removed that, the async tests run fine.  However..  I need make that call for some tests.

Comment: Is there a reason, why you create the component inside each test case instead of doing it seperately? As far as I can see, the standard spec setup looks like only the TestBed setup is run as async, the component is generally created just inside a beforeEach loop before the test cases and is not asynchronous. Once your fixture and component creation is separate you are able to run your test cases asynchronous if needed for your test case (e.g. observables are involved etc.)